# AutoHotkey's hotkeys do not work in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, autohotkey

Certain inventory operations are ridiculously tedious in Skyrim. I wrote myself a script that would sell my items one by one, because according to internet wisdom, you do not get Speech experience for every sold item if you sell them as stack.

The script looks like this (works only with the skyUI plugin):

```
toggle=0

F7::
If (toggle := !toggle)
{
  SetTimer, Timer, -1
}
return

timer:
while toggle
{
  Send {e down}
  Sleep, 50
  Send {e up}
  if (!toggle) {
    break
  }
  Sleep, 100
  if (!toggle) {
    break
  }
  Send {HOME down}
  Sleep, 50
  Send {HOME up}
  Sleep, 100
}
return
```

It works perfectly if I assign <kbd>F12</kbd> as hotkey, but I am using that one for a script that just spams <kbd>E</kbd>. So what's wrong, why is <kbd>F12</kbd> the only hotkey that seems to work in Skyrim?

Comment: So, are you using a similar script for F12 and it's working as expected?

Comment: yes, and if I use this script with F12 hotkey, it works too. I tried several other keys, namely F1, F7 and K, none of them worked. All of the keys worked outside skyrim (eg. in text editor). Currently, I simply have all scripts running for F12 and I use the Suspend hotkeys feature to alter them.

Comment: Just open the console and give yourself 100 speech.

Comment: A non-console alternative is to create something super expensive, potion or weapon, and buy/sell it repeatedly.